# Is there a way to know what passed through a if statement

Tags: c#

My problem is, that I need to now, what statements passed through a If statement. The code is as follows.

```
int[] Array = {value1,value2,value3}
foreach {int Value in Array)
{
if (Value < 4)
{
    // Here i need to know what values passed through that were less that 4, like    
    // which one, value 1, value 2, and/or value 3
}
```

So is there a solution for a problem? I'm kind of new to programming.
My problem is that i do not need an else statement, i Need to know if value 1 or 2 or 3 passed through. Exactly which ones are less than 4. EDIT: fixed some mistakes, was in a rush, forgot to put the sign the other way. When they are less than 4, i need to now which values passed through. Ill prob repost tho. As i messed up. I really don't care for now which ones are greater, or the else statement, i skipped that part.
Edit2: I also came up with a solution, but i don't if its good. Should i run a loop when i store values in the if statement, making another if statement, to compare if the ones inside the if statement are the same on the outside, and then knowing which values passed through?

Comment: use else if (Value < 4){ //what you want to do }

Comment: What about the ones that are exactly equal to 4, do you want to know about them as well?

Comment: Most of the answers have suggested using `else`. Didn't your programming teacher or the tutorial you're learning from show the full structure of an `if` statement? This is really basic stuff to be asking here.

Comment: @Barmar I messed up the question. I skipped the else on purpose as it was not needed. I messed up the sign, giving everyone here confusion.

Comment: What confused everyone is that you said "what values", but you meant "what indexes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about use for instead of foreach, since you got index of array member, you will know which one *passed through*

```
int[] array = {value1, value2, value3}
for (int index = 0; index < array.Count(); index++)
{
    if (array[index] < 4)
    {
        // do sth with index
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Never thought of that! Was in A rush, and kinda late were I live.

Comment: Funny, once upon a time this was the only way to loop through an array. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% positive if I understand the question but it seems you can use the `else` statement

```
if (Value > 4)
{
 // Do your stuff for elements greater than 4
}
else
{
 // Do your stuff for elements greater lower or equal than 4
}
```

Comment: No, I want to know what values pass through, which ones are less than 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
int Array[] = {value1,value2,value3}
foreach {int Value in Array)
{
if (Value > 4)
{
    // Here i need to know what elements passed through that were less that 4
}else if(Value < 4){
  //values < 4 will execute this code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a few general suggestions that should hopefully be helpful. First of all, your conditional says `if (Value > 4)` so you will not go into that code block where you suggest figuring out which elements are less than 4. Instead you'd need an `else`. So here's one way;

```
int Array[] = {value1,value2,value3}
List<int> lessThanFour = new List<int>();
foreach {int Value in Array)
{
    if (Value < 4)
    {
        lessThanFour.Add(Value);
        Console.WriteLine(Value);
    }
}
```

The above code puts each value which is less than four into a list so you can access them later. It also prints them to the console.

Another option would be to use LINQ;

```
var lessThanFour = Array.Where(x => x < 4);
foreach (int c in lessThanFor)
    Console.WriteLine(c);
```

The above code uses the `Where` operator to create a new array with all ints in the original that have a value less than for. The statement `x => x < 4` is best to think of in an iterative since where `x` is the current element. It works the same as the foreach loop. When you execute that code it basically says, for each int x in Array, if x is less than four add it to the result. Then I use a foreach below that to print out the results.

Comment: Yeah but using LINQ Won't help my problem, First off, I put the > sign the wrong, way, its fixed now, But i Need to now if Value1, Value2, or Value3 passed through.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is poorly framed I think but it sounds like you are looking for a switch case.

```
if (x < 4) {
   switch (x) {

       case 1: 
           Console.WriteLine("Case 1");
           break;

       case 2:
           Console.WriteLine("Case 2");
           break;

       case 3:
           Console.WriteLine("Case 3");
           break;

       default:
           Console.WriteLine("Default case");
           break;
    }
}
```